# printing the json array from certain indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

guys i know it is dummy question but i spent several hours and still cant reach .. i want to print a json array from variable startIndex and endIndex .. all what i did is printing it all .. here is my code

```js
GridLibrary.prototype.display = function() {
 $.ajax({

  url : this.getFileName(),
  dataType : "json",
  error : function(that, e) {

   console.log(e);
  },
  success : function(data) {
   size = data.length;
   var html = [];
   html.push("<table >\n<tbody>");
   html.push("<tr>");
   for ( var propertyNames in data[0]) {
    html.push("<th>" + propertyNames + "</th>");
   }
   html.push("</tr>");
   // loop through the array of objects
   data.forEach(function(item) {
    html.push("<tr>");
    for ( var key in item) {
     html.push("<td>" + item[key] + "</td>");
    }
    html.push("</tr>");

   });
   html.push("<table>\n</tbody>");
   $('body').append(html.join(""));

  }

 });
};
```

Comment: Use a `for`loop instead of a `forEach`, and you'll be able to filter your array between `startIndex` and `endIndex`.

Answer (score 0):

try this, loop through only the data you need

```
for( var i = startIndex; var item = data[i]; i<endIndex && typeof item != 'undefined' ; i++){
    html.push("<tr>");
    for ( var key in item) {
        html.push("<td>" + item[key] + "</td>");
    }
    html.push("</tr>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just before your `data.forEach(...)` you could use [splice()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) to cut your data array.

Like this:
`data = data.splice(startIndex, endIndex);`

Comment: @mmmm Could you explain ?